# google script openByUrl autorization, trigger activation

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm quite new to programming and struggling with apps authorization :
I created a code that has to access other files of my Gdrive, with the command `openByUrl`, which sends back an error message, telling me it doesn't have the authorization to perform `openByUrl`.
I went through the oauth2 scopes but can't understand how to give the authorization to my script.

I already have an internet copied script that runs `DriveApp.getFolderById`, but it runs through a menu.
I want both getFolderById and openByUrl to run on a trigger (each day at midnight) thus, it can't run through a menu.

The goal of my script is to list all files in a specified folder, get the spreadsheet ones, and extract specific cells from these spreadsheets.

I got something running with importance, but clearly, it's too bulky to run properly on more than 3000 files.

Could anyone explain to me how to give authorizations to openByUrl please? (even better if in French ;-) )

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

I would create a new project and copy the whole code.

If you want to check why in a particular project you have this error, you can open the manifest file that has the required scopes. You can find it clicking on `Project Settings` on the left bar and then `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor`. The field `oauthScopes` has to contain all the required scopes or has to be deleted.

### Methods explanation:

- [DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) get all the folders with a specified name. Take the first one with `.next()`
- [Folder.getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype) get all the files with a specific [mimetype](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)
- [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) open a specific Spreadsheet document
- [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) get all the sheets in an array
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) get a specific range
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) get the values of a specified range

### Updated code:

```
function main() {

  var folderName = 'folder'
  var type = MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFolders()
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next()
    console.log(folder.getName())
    var files = folder.getFilesByType(type)
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next()
      console.log(file.getName() + ': ' + file.getid())
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getid()).getSheets()
      var values = sheets[0].getRange('A1:B2').getValues()
      console.log(values)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I got it runing! last problem is, it has to get the files from folders inside the main folder, which doesn't seem to work with this code, as the files are "hided" to the code by the sub-folders.

Comment: Do you have more folders within those subfolders that contain files? I ask this to know if a recursive function is needed or if it would be enough to just take all the files inside the subfolders of the main folder.

Comment: no, there's only 2 stages of folders, the one main which for all my applicants,  containing sub-folders for each applicant, containing resume, motivation letter and information spreadsheet for each applicant
my spreadsheet's goal is to get the information of all applicants' spreadsheets to make some sort of annuary

Comment: I have updated the code, it gets all the folders from the main folder and then all the files in each folder found. I hope it now works as expected.